# Cómo contar en sql en una consulta anidada?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Necesito listar información acerca de un cliente que tenga en su nombre la cadena Jos, con un contrato activo y cuyo vehículo haya sufrido al menos 2 accidentes, tengo las siguientes tablas:

```
CREATE TABLE PERSONA(
    ID_PERSONA SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    CI BIGINT NOT NULL,
    NOMBRE_PERSONA VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE CLIENTE(
    ID_CLIENTE SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES PERSONA(ID_PERSONA)
);

CREATE TABLE CONTRATA_VEHICULO(
    ID_CLIENTE SERIAL NOT NULL REFERENCES CLIENTE(ID_CLIENTE),
    ESTADO_CONTRATO VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL CHECK(ESTADO_CONTRATO = 'ACTIVO' OR ESTADO_CONTRATO = 'NO ACTIVO'
);

CREATE TABLE INVOLUCRA(
    NRO_REFERENCIA_ACC SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ID_PERSONA SERIAL NOT NULL REFERENCES PERSONA(ID_PERSONA)
);

CREATE TABLE CATEGORIA_ACCIDENTE(
    ID_CATEGORIA_ACC SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    DESCRIP_SUBCATEG VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);
```

Intenté con este query:

```
SELECT id_persona AS Identificacion, ci AS Cedula, nombre_persona AS Nombre 
FROM persona WHERE nombre_persona = 'Jos%' AND id_persona IN (
    SELECT id_cliente FROM cliente WHERE id_cliente IN (
        SELECT id_cliente FROM contrata_vehiculo WHERE estado_contrato = 'ACTIVO' AND COUNT(
            SELECT id_cliente FROM contrata_vehiculo WHERE id_cliente IN (
                SELECT id_persona FROM involucra WHERE nro_referencia_acc IN (
                    SELECT nro_referencia_acc FROM accidente WHERE id_categoria IN (
                        SELECT id_categoria_acc FROM categoria_accidente WHERE descrip_subcateg = 'Choque'
                    )
                )
            )
        ) >= 2
    )
)
```

Para listar las personas cuyos nombres posean la subcadena Jos, que tengan un contrato activo, y que hayan sufrido al menos 2 accidentes, pero me sale un error en el COUNT(SELECT ...) en la linea 5. Con el count(select) pretendía crear la condición de que solo aceptara las personas que tienen al menos 2 accidentes con la subcategoria 'choque'

Answer (score 0):

---

### Intenta con este sql

```
SELECT per.id_persona AS Identificacion, per.ci AS Cedula, per.nombre_persona AS Nombre
FROM persona per
    JOIN cliente cli on cli.id_cliente = per.id_persona
    JOIN contrata_vehiculo cv on cv.id_cliente = cli.id_cliente and cv.estado_contrato = 'ACTIVO'
    JOIN involucra invol on invol.id_persona = cv.id_cliente
    JOIN accidente acc on acc.nro_referencia_acc = invol.nro_referencia_acc
    JOIN categoria_accidente cata on cata.id_categoria_acc = acc.id_categoria
WHERE per.nombre_persona like 'Jos%'
  AND cata.descrip_subcateg = 'Choque'
GROUP BY per.id_persona, per.ci, per.nombre_persona 
HAVING count(cv.id_persona) >= 2
```